# check if reset password token Valid laravel

Tags: php, laravel, token, laravel-7

i am trying to check if this token and this email exist in passwrod_reset table but the problem my token in decrypted and the token in table in encrypted so how can i check the token if its in table or not ?

```
public function checkData(Request $request){

   return DB::table('password_resets')->where(['token' => $request->token , 'email'=> $request->email])->exists();
   
}
```

> received data from Request `dd($request->all());`

```
array:2 [
  "email" => "asd@asd.com"
  "token" => "6afa1b987d67bfbb9a599a3e30c45942a71b1e518d7406dbcf3b3266d689f732"
]
```

> and finally the token in DB table password_resets

```
#items: array:1 [
    0 => {#351
      +"email": "asd@asd.com"
      +"token": "$2y$10$QNKyX42nm4W1MHZdeIUmBuNimeftiDnQQUCyZfDDgTwlbiRL//hsO"
      +"created_at": "2020-08-25 21:26:42"
    }
  ]
```

all in all...how to check this decrypted token that is come from request `6afa1b987d67bfbb9a599a3e30c45942a71b1e518d7406dbcf3b3266d689f732` with this encrypted token `$2y$10$QNKyX42nm4W1MHZdeIUmBuNimeftiDnQQUCyZfDDgTwlbiRL//hsO` that is come from DataBase

Comment: no..i am sure there is a function that can read the dycrepted token..but i cant find it

Comment: not me..laravel do that

Comment: i am just using password_reset without all laravel/ui ? like previous versions of laravel

Comment: can you share your `config/hashing.php` file to check you laravel hashes the token?

Comment: let me tell something this decrypted token its came from my angular frontend after send email to reset password so mail sender make it decrypted

Comment: you need to know the encrypting algorithm otherwise you can not compare those tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is here..

in my forgetPassword Controller

```
    public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher)
    {
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }

      public function checkData(Request $request){
        $reset = DB::table('password_resets')->where(['email'=> $request->email])->first();
        if(!$reset){
            return false;
        }
        if($this->hasher->check($request->token, $reset->token)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
```